# How to override index signatures

Tags: typescript

How do I create an `Array` derivative but with a different index signature?

For example

```
interface SaferArray<T> extends Array<T> {
  [i: number]: T | undefined
}
```

Error:

```
Interface incorrectly extends interface 'T[]'.
  Index signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'T | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a type alias:

```
type SaferArray<T> = Array<T | undefined>;

const example: SaferArray<string> = ["hello"];

const a = example[0]; // string | undefined
const b = example[1]; // string | undefined
```

It is possible to extend if you prefer. You're just missing the `| undefined` in the type you're extending:

```
interface SaferArray<T> extends Array<T | undefined> {
  [i: number]: T | undefined
}
```